# How to diagnose/fix timeouts on file dialogs

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus

My Ubuntu regularly gets in a pickle with opening file dialogues/dialogs for some reason - e.g. "Open File..." or "Save as..." or just trying to open a Nautilus window.

It causes the app that wanted to use the dialog to freeze up for minutes, giving me the "xxxx app is not responding, Force Quit/Wait?" If I wait long enough it will come up, but this can be several minutes.

`top` says nothing, syslog says nothing (or nothing *relevant* I think).

How can I find out what's hanging it?

I'm on 20.04 with vanilla Gnome Shell.

Comment: New or has always done this?

Comment: honestly it comes and goes. New. Sometimes I think it's to do with a samba share (in /etc/fstab, not gfs) I use combined with frequent suspend/resume + changing wifis. But `umount -l /the/share` doesn't fix it, so maybe it's not that. It's definitely a timeout of something though, just can't tell what it's waiting for!

Comment: Are you sure the external drive is not going into a sleep mode and the delay is the drive spinning up?

Comment: It is an external drive (attached to a raspberry pi which shares using samba) but that drive is in near constant use, so it's not turning off.